# Inline/shorthand types in C#

Tags: c#

In TypeScript I can declare an array such as:

```
const arr: { id: number; value: string; }[] = [];
```

Is there a shorthand way I could do something similar in C#?

```
var list = new List<{ int id; string value; }>();
```

I find myself mutating and mapping lists a lot and it gets cumbersome to explicitly declare classes and interfaces for each different operation.

Comment: You might wanna use `System.Tuple`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uhhm, you could use a `List<()>`, so called [named Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples):

```
var list = new List<(int id, string value)>();
```

And use it in the same way as if you're working with a list of objects:

```
var obj = list.First();
Console.WriteLine($"{obj.id}-{obj.value}");
```